# JQuery script not working with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this marquee plugin for JQuery:
http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm

This creates a streaming ticker out of ul and li elements. I am using imbedded Ruby (Ruby on Rails) to provide the data.

This works on the Mac using Safari and Firefox, and on Windows using Firefox, but does not work with Windows on IE8. I'm having similar problems on another page that is using JQuery. Basically, it is not functional in Internet Explorer 8.

I've researched this but can't seem to find the specific answer I need to make this work. One post I read suggested using `$(window).load(function) {`  instead of `$(document).ready(function) {`

I appreciate the help. I'm fairly new to JQuery.

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#marquee").marquee();
  $("#marquee").marquee("update");
});
</script>


<div id="prayers">
<!-- this loop is necessary to iterate through the array passed in @prayers -->
        <ul id="marquee" class="marquee">
        <% @prayers.each do |prayer| %>

            <li><%= prayer.first_name %> from <%= prayer.city %> prays: "<%= prayer.request %>"</li>

        <% end %>

        <li>This is a scrolling prayer. Check it out</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the plugin and tested in FF, IE and Chrome and it was working fine for me. One thing I did noticed though is that the plugin would not work if you do not  add the css file to your page (jquery.marquee.css).

```
<link href="Styles/jquery.marquee.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

After I added that the plugin worked everywhere. If it does not work for you maybe check IE's Security Tab and make sure you can run Javascript from it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What version of IE were you using? I can make it work in IE9, but not IE8. Yes, the CSS is critical to the functionality, but I have that and it is working in other browsers. There is something in IE8 that is simply not working.

Comment: @SteveCervera I was using IE8 when I tested, this is pretty strange that it is not working for you.